# Synset cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, jsp

```
    String[] args=request.getParameterValues("text1");

    System.setProperty("wordnet.database.dir", "C:/Program Files/WordNet/2.1/dict/");
    if (args.length > 0)
    {
        //  Concatenate the command-line arguments
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            buffer.append((i > 0 ? " " : "") + args[i]);
        }
        String wordForm = buffer.toString();
        //  Get the synsets containing the wrod form
        WordNetDatabase database = WordNetDatabase.getFileInstance();
        Synset[] synsets = database.getSynsets(wordForm);
        //  Display the word forms and definitions for synsets retrieved
        if (synsets.length > 0)
        {
            out.println("The following synsets contain '" +
                    wordForm + "' or a possible base form " +
                    "of that text:");
            for (int i = 0; i < synsets.length; i++)
            {
                out.println("");
                String[] wordForms = synsets[i].getWordForms();
                for (int j = 0; j < wordForms.length; j++)
                {
                    out.print((j > 0 ? ", " : "") +
                            wordForms[j]);
                }
                out.println(": " + synsets[i].getDefinition());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            out.println("No synsets exist that contain " +
                    "the word form '" + wordForm + "'");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        out.println("You must specify " +
                "a word form for which to retrieve synsets.");
    }
```

error :

```
An error occurred at line: 29 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Synset cannot be resolved to a type
26:             String wordForm = buffer.toString();
27:             //  Get the synsets containing the wrod form
28:             WordNetDatabase database = WordNetDatabase.getFileInstance();
29:             Synset[] synsets = database.getSynsets(wordForm);
30:             //  Display the word forms and definitions for synsets retrieved
31:             if (synsets.length > 0)
32: 

        {
```

Stacktrace:

```
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: What do your imports look like?

Comment: import edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.*;
import edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.Synset;
import edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.WordNetDatabase;

Comment: That's very odd - I'd expect the *import* to fail if it couldn't find the type. Are you sure you've got those imports within the same file that's failing?